# Knockout select field error databind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would to create a drop down list using Knockout. This is my select:

I don't understand why the *"value"* of my select field works only when I change the selection and do not work on the first time loading. I would the direct positioning on the element of *'Misure'* (ObservableArray in the options) and I have always white space. The code is the follow:

```
self.MisuraLaboratorio = ko.observable();

self.MisuraLaboratorio = function () { 
    if (self.Indicazione() != null) { 
        for (i = 0; i < self.Misure().length; i++) { 
            if (self.Indicazione().Misura.Id == self.Misure()[i].Id) { 
                var data = self.Misure()[i]; 
                return data; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    return " "; 
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you to set an observable, you want to call it as a function with the value like:

```
self.MisuraLaboratorio(yourValue);
```

It looks like you are overwriting it with a function that finds your value.

Comment: If I use the follow method, worked but when I change element on the select I have undefined element.Why?
<select class="field col1h" id="selMisura" data-bind="options: Misure, optionsText: 'Descrizione', optionValue: 'Id', value: MisuraLaboratorio(), event: { change: modificaMisura }" />

Comment: what is the difference between value: MisuraLaboratorio() and  value: MisuraLaboratorio. Why the first time I can view the initial element and not the other but in the second time I can't view the first element but the other selected are good? I don't understanding

Comment: When you do a two-way binding like with the `value` binding, you need to pass just the observable. If you pass `MisuraLaboratorio()` then it will just be the final value and the binding will have no way to get back to the observable (so that it can write to it).

Comment: thanks man, I resolve in this way:
<input class="col1" type="text" id="txtVal" maxlength="6" data-bind="value: Valore, numericOptions: {}, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keyup: calcoloValore }, numeric: {}" />

Comment: and the code is:
self.MisuraLaboratorio = ko.computed(function () {
        var idMisura = 0;
            if (self.Indicazione() != null) {
                for (i = 0; i < self.Misure().length; i++) {
                    if (self.Indicazione().Misura.Id == self.Misure()[i].Id) {
                        idMisura = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (idMisura > 0)
            return self.Misure() != null ? self.Misure()[idMisura] : "";
        else
            return self.Misure() != null ? self.Misure()[0] : "";
    }, self);